# How to create animations for 2D slices of a 3D volume with overlapping mask

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to create a Matplotlib animation by plotting the 2D slices of a 3D brain MRI volume frame by frame. However, I also want to overlap each frame with its corresponding segmentation mask with manageable opacity.
I tried to do the following. `X_test` is a tensor of size (1, 128, 128, 128, 4) for 4 different modes of imaging, of which I am only using the first mode.
`y_test` also has the same size but it is the segmentation map with each of the 4 channels denoting one hot encoded masks, I excluded the first channel since it classifies the background.

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
slices = []
for i in range(128):
    
    ax = plt.imshow(X_test[0, :, :, i, 0], animated=True)
    ax = plt.imshow(y_test[0, :, :, i, 1:4], animated=True, interpolation='none', alpha=0.5)
    slices.append([ax])
    
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, slices, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=500)
ani.save('dynamic_images.mp4')
plt.show()
```

When I do this, I end up with an animation that shows just a blank image in its entirety.
However, when I plot a single slice individually, like this:

```
plt.imshow(X_test[0, :, :, i, 0])
plt.imshow(y_test[0, :, :, i, 1:4], interpolation='none', alpha=0.5)
```

It shows the two images overlapped on top of each other.
How do I make this overlapped image appear as the frames in my animation?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: One thing I noticed is you are overwriting `ax` before you append it to `slices`. Could it be the problem?

Comment: Nope. Tried without the overwriting but didn't work.